# Youtube how to show video controls (Watch later, Share)

Tags: youtube

I don't know why the share button is not showing on my videos.
I just have a text "copy link"

The videos are integrated into a wordpress

Here is an example, the first video which is not mine and the second which is from my channel

[image]

Do I have to change a parameter ?

Comment: Please provide the code you're using for create this.

Comment: I have no code, it's just un copy paste yoube url in wordpress article

Comment: Provide the YouTube URL you're copy/pasting. maybe the problem is the URL, try, for example copy/past this URL and check the results: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/hKAo3uhpJ9E`

Comment: I tried with the url https://www.youtube.com/embed/22HmEizs0rM

But it does not change anything

Not all videos on my channel have the share button

Comment: @Jenechal, searching on Google, it seems that this "feature" is on YouTube kids, since your vieo is on YouTube Kids, your vide is shown with the "copy link" instead of "share". See this [link](https://www.xelium.co.uk/2020/04/how-to-remove-copy-link-from-the-top-right-corner-of-embedded-youtube-video/) for more details - or this [answer on YouTube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/27555353?hl=en&msgid=27804147). Unfortunately, I don't know about YouTube Kids, so, these are my two cents. Hope it helps.

Comment: Ho  yes if I uncheck "Oui, elle est conçue pour les enfants" share button appears !

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your video has the check "Yes, it is designed for children" and [you confirm in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63825761/youtube-how-to-show-video-controls-watch-later-share?noredirect=1#comment113054175_63825761) that when you unchecked this option, the "Share" button is enabled in your embed videos.

It seems this feature is not documented (*neither clear, in my opinion*) and I only could find these two link that talks about YouTube kids and this behavior in embed videos.

- [answer on YouTube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/27555353?hl=en&msgid=27804147)
- [How to remove “Copy Link” from the top right corner of embedded YouTube Video - Made for Kids](https://www.xelium.co.uk/2020/04/how-to-remove-copy-link-from-the-top-right-corner-of-embedded-youtube-video/)

So, the solution is: uncheck the "Yes, it is designed for children" option mark.